# Tabulator.js not loading data via AJAX in Laravel blade view

Tags: laravel, tabulator

I am making a test App in Laravel 10 and I want to use Tabulator.js to display data. I am not getting any error so far, but the grid is shown empty.
The version of Tabulator I am using is 5.5.2 (latest at the time of this post).

This is my code so far (product.js):

```
import { Tabulator, AjaxModule } from 'tabulator-tables'
import '../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

   var table = new Tabulator("#grid", {
      ajaxURL: "/dashboard/getProducts",
      index: "productId",
      height: "300px",
      placeholder: "No data available",
      layout: "fitDataStretch",
      autoResize: true,
      columns: [
         { title: "", field: "productId", visible: false },
         { title: "", field: "userId", visible: false },
         { title: "Code", field: "productCode", width: 90 },
         { title: "Description", field: "description", width: 450 },
         { title: "Price", field: "price", width: 90 }
      ],
   })

})
```

**--- THE THINGS I HAVE TRIED: ---**

I have tried the examples given in the official website and in SO without success.
Even the simplest of all the Tabulator site examples, do not show any data and, strangely, there is no sign of any AJAX request done so far, in the browser console, after loading the view.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#grid", {
   ajaxURL:"/dashboard/getProducts",
});
```

I was, however, able to get the data in a different way, which I consider inappropriate given the features they provided in this library:

```
   axios.get('/dashboard/getProducts').then(res => {
      var table = new Tabulator("#grid", {
         data: res.data,
         index: "productId",
         height: "300px",
         placeholder: "No data available",
         layout: "fitDataStretch",
         autoResize: true,
         columns: [
            { title: "", field: "productId", visible: false },
            { title: "", field: "userId", visible: false },
            { title: "Code", field: "productCode", width: 90, editor: "input" },
            { title: "Description", field: "description", width: 450, editor: "input" },
            { title: "Price", field: "price", hozAlign: "right", width: 90, editor: true },
            { title: "Active?", field: "active", editor: "list", width: 90, editorParams: { values: { "Y": "Yes", "N": "No" } } },
         ],
      })
   })
   .catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
         Notify('error', error.response.data)
      }
   })
```

At some point I thought the problem of not getting data was the lack of CSRF token, but it is a GET request and, even if I include it in the headers, no data is returned.
I also tried writing the tabulator configuration separated from the data loading by calling the `table.setData()` method separately, but with same result.

I have also got rid of the columns definition and let `autoColumns` create them automatically, just to check for any wrong line, but the result is exactly the same: "No data available".

Obviously, there is data in the database and it is returned in the format expected by Tabulator. I tried using absolute and relative URLs with no luck.

Can anyone see anything I didn't see? what's wrong in my code?

**EDIT**: I added the blade view code on request and the complete JS code was updated above.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div id="grid" class="col-6"></div>
   </div>
@endsection

@push('js')
   @vite(['resources/js/product.js'])
@endpush
```

My controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\product;

class productController extends Controller
{
   // The model to be managed by this controller.
   private $product;

   public function __construct() {
      // Instantiate the model.
      $this->product = new product();
   }


   public function getProducts() {
      return $this->product->getAllRows();
   }
}
```

Here is the method called by getAllRows() from the model class:

```
   /**
    * Return all rows from the table.
    * return array
    */
   public function getAllData() {
      $query = "SELECT ".$this->getColumns()." FROM ".$this->table." WHERE deleted <> 'Y';";
      $result = DB::select($query);
      return $result;
   }
```

The method is returning the JSON data correctly. That has already been tested.

Comment: I think it is useful to tell that no request is shown in the browser console. It is as if the AJAX component is not working at all in Tabulator.js

Comment: What happens instead? As Laravel is running on the server, and Tabulator in die browser, I would assume that the markup generated by Laravel is not sound?

Comment: @Nico Haase     There is no generated code by Laravel. Both the blade view and the JS file were written manually. Remember that this is a test App only, nothing serious. It is just to come to know how to use Tabulator.

Comment: Can you share the **generated** markup? What have you tried to check where this goes wrong?

Comment: @NicoHaase     I added the code of the blade view and the controller, if it is what you meant. I also updated the code of the JS file above.

Comment: You haven't shared the **generated** markup yet, not any rprecise description about what is not working yet

Comment: @NicoHaase     Do you mean the page source? what are you expecting to find there? if I may know.  The problem is in the description above (empty grid, no data returned).

Comment: If the problem is "empty grid", what have you tried to resolve that? If the request itself does not return any data, are you sure this problem is related to Tabulator after all? Why not check that, and afterwards remove the irrelevant parts from your post? Is the proper controller called? Does it run the proper statements on your database (which might be hidden behind `$this->product->getAllRows()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, today I could finally dedicate a bit of time to study this issue and the Tabulator documentation with detail and I found the solution to my problem.

For anyone out there using Tabulator for the first time, take into account that to use a module, it is not enough to import it, but to **register** it as well by calling the method `registerModule`, so this is my final working code:

```
import { Tabulator, AjaxModule, FormatModule, EditModule } from "tabulator-tables"
import '../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

   Tabulator.registerModule([FormatModule, EditModule, AjaxModule]);

   var table = new Tabulator("#grid", {
      ajaxURL: "/getProducts",
      index: "productId",
      height: "300px",
      placeholder: "No data available",
      layout: "fitDataStretch",
      autoResize: true,
      columns: [
         { title: "", field: "productId", visible: false },
         { title: "", field: "userId", visible: false },
         { title: "Code", field: "productCode", width: 90 },
         { title: "Description", field: "description", width: 450 },
         { title: "Price", field: "price", width: 90 }
      ],
   })
})
```

Now it works as expected.